# Mongoose - Import schema for a sub document

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

In my Nodejs server I'm using mongoose
And I've created schemas for posts and comments in a single file.
Is there any way to export the schema for the sub document (comments) to seperate file and import to main schema file?

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const commentSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    body: { type: String }
});

const postSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    title: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    comments: {
        type: [commentSchema]
    }
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('questions', postSchema);
```

Comment: Really not clear what you are asking here. Could you elaborate with examples of what you expect to happen please.

Comment: You either declare the sub-schema on an `fileA` and import it into your `fileB` and `fileC` to use.

Or you can export the model and the sub schema from your file.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can like below example,

**Child Schema**

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const ChildSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name : String,    
});


module.exports = mongoose.model('Child',ChildSchema)
```

**Parent Schema**

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const child = require('./child') // import it from path

const ParentSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name : String,
    
    childs : [child.schema], // use it like this
    child : child.schema    //or like this
    
});


module.exports = mongoose.model('Parent',ParentSchema)
```